# How to parse text file using unique delimiters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, text-files, delimiter

Python 3.5.2 on Spyder 2.x

I have thousands of text files which are in the following format kind of semi-structured.

The below is one file one.txt:

```
Goodsign:       Klisti upto 15:57         Bad Omen:     Gated zone      
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
Dusk Attack:        Uptime      Dusk Rest:      Winters
```

The below is second file second.txt

```
Goodsign:       Kukul upto 12:60          Bad Omen:     Open zone       
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
Dusk Attack:        Downtime        Dusk Rest:      Summers Daring Tribe: Mojars of Moana
```

Now I want to parse both these files and get the values for the labels Goodsign: which is "Klisti upto 15:57" in one.txt and "Kukul upto 12:60" in second case.

For the next set of variables again the same Bad Omen: get value "Gated zone" and second case Bad Omen: "Open zone".

for the next set of variables again ignore &nbsp and get value for label "Dusk Attack:" repeat the same for label "Dusk Rest:"

the problem apart from the : delimiter there seems to be a tab delimiter between the values such as between  Downtime       Dusk Rest: there is a gap "     " is this tab or how to parse this kind of text?

I tried implementing below code but how to use for only delimiter "Dusk Rest:" for example but it gives all values after that. I need only value "Downtime" whereas it gives me "Downtime       Dusk Rest:      Summers  Daring Tribe: Mojars of Moana" :

```
f = open('one.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
searchtxt="Dusk Rest:"
for i, line in enumerate(lines):    
    if searchtxt in line and i+1 < len(lines):
    #print(lines[i+1])
    print(line)
    break
```

Many thanks in advance for your valuable answers!

Comment: Is there more than one block like that per file?

Comment: yes per file single block not repeated in same file "Dusk Rest:" appears only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to work with these files is to split them on a regex, perhaps like this.

The useful bits of information seem to be separated by at least two consecutive items of whitespace. We can split on those. At the same time we can arrange to eliminate the leading no-backspace HTML elements, if we can assume that they are always of the form `&nbsp;\s`. Otherwise they would have to be treated separately. Having split the fields we can use the `list` type's `index` method to find the field names in the split items to form the values. (This allows for the possibility that we have split the file's contents somewhere inappropriately; we can glue a field back together.

```
import re

for file_name in ['one.txt', 'second.txt']:
    print (file_name)
    with open(file_name) as f:
        content = f.read()
        items = re.split(r'\s{2,}(?:&nbsp;\s)*', content)
        print (items)
        results = {}
        results['Goodsign:'] = ' '.join(items[1: items.index('Bad Omen:')])
        results['Bad Omen:'] = ' '.join(items[1+items.index('Bad Omen:'): items.index('Dusk Attack:')])
        results['Dusk Rest:'] = ' '.join(items[1+items.index('Dusk Attack:'):])
        results['Dusk Attack:'] = ' '.join(items[1+items.index('Dusk Attack:'): items.index('Dusk Rest:')])
        results['Dusk Rest:'] = ' '.join(items[1+items.index('Dusk Rest:'):])
        for result in results:
            print (result, results[result])
```

And here's the output:

```
one.txt
['Goodsign:', 'Klisti upto 15:57', 'Bad Omen:', 'Gated zone', 'Dusk Attack:', 'Uptime', 'Dusk Rest:', 'Winters']
Bad Omen: Gated zone
Goodsign: Klisti upto 15:57
Dusk Attack: Uptime
Dusk Rest: Winters
second.txt
['Goodsign:', 'Kukul upto 12:60', 'Bad Omen:', 'Open zone', 'Dusk Attack:', 'Downtime', 'Dusk Rest:', 'Summers']
Bad Omen: Open zone
Goodsign: Kukul upto 12:60
Dusk Attack: Downtime
Dusk Rest: Summers
```

Comment: Your code worked only till building the items the results started giving error so I created my own code but will accept your answer as it may help comeone in the future. @Bill Bell

Comment: If you supply the item that raised the error I can try to diagnose the error.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the string comprised of your two examples:

```
>>> txt="""\
... Goodsign:       Klisti upto 15:57         Bad Omen:     Gated zone      
... &nbsp;
... &nbsp;
... Dusk Attack:        Uptime      Dusk Rest:      Winters
... Goodsign:       Kukul upto 12:60          Bad Omen:     Open zone       
... &nbsp;
... &nbsp;
... Dusk Attack:        Downtime        Dusk Rest:      Summers
... """
```

You can use a regex to get the values following specific fields:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat1=r'^Goodsign:[ \t]*(.*?)[ \t]*(?=Bad Omen:)'
>>> pat2=r'Bad Omen:[ \t]*(.*?)[ \t]*\n'
>>> re.findall(pat1, txt, re.M)
['Klisti upto 15:57', 'Kukul upto 12:60']
>>> re.findall(pat2, txt)
['Gated zone', 'Open zone']
```

And so on.

If the fields are `\t` separated (which you example is not), your regex's become monumentally easier to write.

---

*Edit based on comment*

Python 3 is strongly typed. Your error is based whatever `items` is being used as a string.

It should work if you do something like:

```
for fn in [something that generates a list of file names...]
    with open(fn) as f:
        txt=f.read()
        m=re.search(pat1, txt, re.M)
        if m:
            print(m.group(1))
```

Comment: The problem with your code is txt variable is in String format whereas when I read data it is in list format so the below gives an error              type(items)
str1 = ''.join(items)
print(str1)
pat1=r'^Nakshatra:[ \t]*(.*?)[ \t]*(?=Yoga:)'
re.findall(pat1, items, re.M)                                                                                                        TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in the findall() function       WHEN I CONVERT LIST TO STRING THE ABOVE ERROR COMES DO YOU KNOW HOW TO GET AROUND THAT?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if understood your question right...but i think your seaching for the escape sequenz \t for tabs. I think you know how to use it.

Comment: Nope in this case I do not know how to use the escape sequence '\t' and ':' delimiters